# How can I change navbar toggler button position on small screen in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and here i made a navbar which puts navbar brand at the center and navlinks on the both sides of the navbar. But here the problem is as soon it hits the small screen navbar toggler button appears at the center just after navbar-brand and i don't want this I want the toggler button to be on the right side of the screen.

Here is my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">EDITION</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-auto order-0">
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">Brand</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I tried using media queries something like this but its not working.

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
            .navbar-toggler {
                transform: translateX(50px) !important;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move out the toggler-button out of the brand container.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">

  <!-- first navigation -->
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">EDITION</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- brand -->
  <div class="mx-auto order-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <!-- toggle button for navigations -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- second navigation -->
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```